# checkcolumn tooltip from a database field

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I want to add a tooltip to checkcolumn but text is a data field.

I tried it -

> ```
>  columns: {
>     defaults: { menuDisabled: false, hideable: false, autoSizeColumn: true },
>     items: [               
>         { text: 'Start', dataIndex: 'start_date', style: 'text-align:left', align: 'left'},
>         { text: 'Stop', dataIndex: 'stop_date', style: 'text-align:left', align: 'left' },            
>         { xtype: 'checkcolumn', text: 'Error', tooltip: 'error_desc', dataIndex: 'error_flag', style: 'text-align:left', align: 'center'}           
>     ]
> }
> ```

If you see my code, i am trying to assign value to tooltip from a database field 'error_desc'.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the renderer function :-

```
columns: {
    defaults: { menuDisabled: false, hideable: false, autoSizeColumn: true },
    items: [
        { text: 'Start', dataIndex: 'start_date', style: 'text-align:left', align: 'left'},
        { text: 'Stop', dataIndex: 'stop_date', style: 'text-align:left', align: 'left' },
        { 
          xtype: 'checkcolumn', 
          text: 'Error', 
          dataIndex: 'error_flag', 
          style: 'text-align:left', 
          align: 'center',
          renderer: function(value, metaData, record) {
                                var error_flag = record.get('error_flag');
                                metaData.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + error_flag + '"';
                                return new Ext.ux.CheckColumn().renderer(value);
           }
    }]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply .. Its works perfectly fine.